# What is ns_error_failure

Tags: firefox

This error shows up in various circumstances in Firefox.

I can't find any description of it.

Googling for `error code "ns_error_failure" site:developer.mozilla.org` returns 4 results, non of them defining the error.

It would be some help with debugging to understand what it means.

Comment: ns_error_failure is a generic error for gecko engine; with no specific details

Comment: please add some kind of source to this and I'd accept this as an anwser